# Register devices - PushApps API

Tags: push-notification, push, pushapps

In PushApps API I see that there is a method called RegisterDevice. Do I have to use it in order to register devices to PushApps, or can I just use the mobile SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Using the SDK is enough for registering devices. This method is for apps that didn't install the SDK and still want to use PushApps for the notifications sending, or for importing a list of push tokens from an external source.